# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context - .filter

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to filter my search bar but I am having problems. I followed a tutorial and copied and pasted this code but I get an error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context " from the line

```
return mod.profileNameLabel.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
```

I am using swift 3 and Xcode 8. I've pasted my code below:

```
var intialProfiles = NSMutablearray()

var profiles = NSMutablearray()

func filterTableView(ind:Int,text:String) {
        switch ind {

        case selectedScope.Name.rawValue:

            //fix of not searching when backspacing
            profiles = intialProfiles.filter(using: { (mod) -> Bool in
            return mod.profileNameLabel.lowered().contains(text.lowercased())
            })
            self.searchTableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: `NSMutableArray` in Swift is horrible. Use native Swift `Array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSMutableArray.filter` accepts a `NSPredicate` as argument, not the `(Profile) -> Bool` closure type that you are passing in.

I recommend you to use a swift array instead of `NSMutableArray`.

I assume the array holds `Profile` objects. If it does not, just replace the word `Profile` in the below code with whatever type it holds.

```
var intialProfiles = [Profile]()

var profiles = [Profile]()

func filterTableView(ind:Int,text:String) {
        switch ind {

        case selectedScope.Name.rawValue:

            //fix of not searching when backspacing
            profiles = intialProfiles.filter { $0.profileNameLabel.lowered().contains(text.lowercased()) }
            self.searchTableView.reloadData()
```

If you insist on using `NSMutableArray`, here is the predicate you need to use:

```
initialProfiles.filter(using: NSPredicate(format: 
    "profileNameLabel contains[c] %@", "Hello"))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried the predicate code you recommended and it removed the error but when I ran it the code doesn't function the way its suppose to i.e searchBar is not filtering the array. Do you know what could be the issue as to why its not running the way it should be?  Also i forgot to mention my array is made up of data retrieved from firebase hence the reason why I'm using a NSMutableArray.

Comment: You can easily convert an `NSMutableArray` to a swift array. I can't find the reason why it does not work just by looking at the code you provided. I need more of your code to figure that out. Maybe you should check the method that calls `filterTableView`. The table view data source methods might also be where the mistake is. Also check if the `filter` bit is executed at all. @j.iese

Comment: ok so I double checked the filter bit and its actually not executing at all. I put a print statement in and only that print is being executed. the code is as follows  func filterTableView(ind:Int,text:String) {
        switch ind {
            
        case selectedScope.Name.rawValue:
            
           profiles.filter(using: NSPredicate(format:
                "profileNameLabel contains[c] %@", "Hello"))
            
           self.searchTableView.reloadData()
        print ("searching")

Comment: I am also calling filterTableView from func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            profiles = NSMutableArray()
            self.searchTableView.reloadData()
        }else {
            filterTableView(ind: searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex, text: searchText)
        }
    }

Comment: @j.iese then check if the search bar delegate method is called. If it is not called, check if you have set the delegate of the search bar to be `self`. Just step through the code and you should be able to find where the mistake is.This is basic debugging and is out of the scope of this question. If you think my answer answer to your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!